# Email Newsletter - Move Right Sidebar Boxes to Left

Tags: html

I have made this newsletter. What I want to do is move the blue and red boxes to the left of the Welcome content.

Can someone please help me. It should be easy but I just can't  do it.

The newsletter: http://pastie.org/private/xaxvrlehkwqrzdmbca

Please excuse my horrible html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put the elements inside the same TR and changed the order.

Check this out http://pastie.org/pastes/8037956

Comment: Not at all! Did you understand the solution?